# Restoring accidentally deleted github auth icon in vscode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I accidentally hid the icon and I don't know how to bring it back.

[image: Accounts icon]

So, now I have to use `ctrl+shift+p` then `GitHub pull request: sign out` then `GitHub pull request: sign in`

Comment: have you looked in your `settings.json` to see if there is a setting related to this button

Comment: i have tried tto delete all of it

Comment: does the command `View: Reset View Locations` help. Maybe you have moved the Container or View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-Click in the Activity bar and select `Accounts`

Answer (score 0):

no, it's this one.

[image]

I have tried your suggestion btw.

Comment: why don't you edit your question, this is not a possible answer